# Redirecting to mobile website with REQUEST_URI appended

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi I want to redirect mobile users to mobile website.
I am using this rewrite rule in htaccess file, which was taken from [detectmobilebrowser.com](http://detectmobilebrowser.com)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} <someconditions here>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} <someconditions here>

RewriteRule ^$ http://m.mysite.com/ [R,L]
```

it is working fine if a mobile user opens url like

> www.mysite.com

user is successfully redirected to

> m.mysite.com

but if user opens a url like

> www.mysite.com/support

then redirection doesn't happen and full version of page is shown to user instead of redirecting to mobile version, I need the user be redirected to

> m.mysite.com/support

similarly

www.mysite.com/contact to  m.mysite.com/contact

In short I want REQUEST_URI to be appended while redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule to match any URI. Currently you have it match `^$`, which is blank and will only match the URI `/`. Try changing that line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: doing this will append the query string, not the request_uri

Comment: @manish The query string is never captured, and is *not* part of the URI that's used to match against the rule's pattern. The query string will **always** be appended to the end unless there's a `?` in the rule's target. If you don't want the query string to automatically be appended, then include a `?` in the end, but the `$1` is the URI, not the query string.